# Cell.selectedBackgroundview not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c

cell.selectedbackgroundview isn't working. I have figured out that the selectedview is placed behind my image in the cell resulting in no visible image (I worked this out by making the image small then a saw the tick behind the image). Is there a way to fix this? My code seems fine it must have something to do with the layers

```
static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
UIImageView *productImages = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
productImages.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[AllProducts_Sections[indexPath.section]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];


cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick 1.png"]];
collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
return cell
```

[image: As you can see the blue is the selected backgroundview and the blackbox is the image why doesnt the selectedbackgorundview go over the black box]

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear what you want to do.

Comment: @Mohan at the moment my cell.selectedbackgroundview is behind my image in the cell and cant see it. I want it in front so I can see it

Comment: you want a transperent tick mark on top of your image?

Comment: then add the imageview as subview first, and then added the tick mark imageview on top of imageview. Set the tickmark alpha value to 0.5 or something.

Comment: The imageview is in front of the tick if I make the image transparent the image looks bad. It was working fine before I wonder what happened

Comment: I was telling add the imageView first and then add the tick imageview as subviews. modify the tick mark imageview's alpha value.

Comment: @Mohan ah ok, figured it out, thanks

Comment: then can you vote up my comment..

Answer (score 0):

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString * cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
  UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
  if (cell==nil) 
  {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
  //some code
  }
  UIView *selectedBackView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
  UIImageView *selectionImg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick 1.png"]];
  [selectedBackView addSubview:selectionImg];
  cell.selectedBackgroundView=selectedBackView;
  return cell;
}
```

Also make sure that tick 1.png is in your project's bundle.